Animated movie/show: Magic world with Multi-Colored Clouds
When I was a kid in the late 1980's I watched an animated movie or tv episode (not sure which) that featured a magical world with multi-colored clouds (red, green, blue, etc).
I believe the clouds were produced by some kind of machine or volcano-like feature.  In the show, the child enters this magical world through an abandoned house.  All I remember is that the house had a painting of a person whose eyes follow the child as he enters the house, and the child wonders-aloud if the house is haunted.
I don't remember much about the child's adventure in the magic world, but in the end the house seems to be magically vaporized into some kind of worm hole, leaving the child back in the real world.
The child then laments that he has no evidence that he ever visited this magical place, but then he looks towards where the house was, and notices that one of the magical creatures he met in this other world was sucked back into the real world with him, proving the place is real. 

This one?

@Walt.  Yes!  As someone who posts a lot of questions online (I'm a programmer), I can't remember ever being this pleasantly surprised with the Internet before.  When I asked the question, I wasn't 100% sure that the memory of the film hadn't been a dream, and I was wondering if readers were going to think I was writing about an LSD trip.  Again, thanks!

No problem. :) Is it alright if I mark it as a duplicate?

@Walt.  Sure, no problem, mark as a duplicate.
